# Utf-8 accent marks error only occuring in Chrome in Rails production on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, utf-8

I have a simple site that has spanish,german team names some with accent marks -  www.ftbll.net/predict/bundesliga. They appear as normal in development mode on chrome but when it's in production on heroku I get errors, e.g `Atlético Madrid` appears as `AtlÃ©tico Madrid`

I have no idea what the problem is or how to solve it!

Comment: Try using more generic font families for utf or make sure the ones you use are Heroku compliant. This is a suggestion, not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could start with your meta tag, not sure if this is going to solve the problem. But I'm sure it's part of the problem.

Your meta tag appears as follows:

```
<meta>charset="utf-8"</meta>
```

And it should looks like this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: @raphael_turtle the first (`<meta>charset="utf-8"</meta>`) is invalid – the `meta` tag is empty (meaning it can’t have any content, only attributes): http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage//semantics.html#the-meta-element

Comment: ok, it's actually compiling from haml,made the change and it's now fixed, though still don't know why I wasn't getting the same error in development!?